# I'm using intl-tel-input library with official phone number validation from the library but "valid" word still shows up even if the input is wrong

Tags: javascript, html, forms, libraries, intl-tel-input

[the image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSZHE.png)
the word "valid" in my form is appear even if the input is too short or invalid.
this is my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test2222.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@18.2.1/build/css/intlTelInput.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">
    <div id="phone_inputs">
    <input id="phone" type="tel">
    <button id="btn" type="button">Validate</button>
    <span id="valid-msg" class="hide">✓ Valid</span>
    <span id="error-msg" class="hide"></span>
</div>
</form>
</body>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@18.2.1/build/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
<script>
    const input = document.querySelector("#phone");
    const button = document.querySelector("#btn");
    const errorMsg = document.querySelector("#error-msg");
    const validMsg = document.querySelector("#valid-msg");
    const errorMap = ["Invalid number", "Invalid country code", "Too short", "Too long", "Invalid number"];
    
    const iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
    utilsScript: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@18.2.1/build/js/utils.js"
});
  const reset = () => {
  input.classList.remove("error");
  errorMsg.innerHTML = "";
  errorMsg.classList.add("hide");
  validMsg.classList.add("hide");
};

// on click button: validate
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  reset();
  if (input.value.trim()) {
    if (iti.isPossibleNumber()) {
      validMsg.classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
      input.classList.add("error");
      const errorCode = iti.getValidationError();
      errorMsg.innerHTML = errorMap[errorCode];
      errorMsg.classList.remove("hide");
    }
  }
});
input.addEventListener('change', reset);
input.addEventListener('keyup', reset);
</script>
</html>
```

i tried to delete the word "valid" from the span tag, the result is the word "valid" not appear even if the input is valid, can you help me please?

Comment: Where do you define the styling rules for the `.hide` class? Nothing actually gets hidden in this snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the `hide` CSS class that the code requires in order to hide the message when it shouldn't be shown.

Also (fyi), your `script` elements are in the wrong place. Nothing is allowed between the closing `body` tag and the closing `html` tag. Your `script` elements should go just BEFORE the closing `body` tag.

Here is the working code. Note that this library not only validates the format of the phone number, but it will also validate the area code as being valid.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test2222.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@18.2.1/build/css/intlTelInput.css">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .hide { display:none; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">
    <div id="phone_inputs">
    <input id="phone" type="tel">
    <button id="btn" type="button">Validate</button>
    <span id="valid-msg" class="hide">✓ Valid</span>
    <span id="error-msg" class="hide"></span>
</div>
</form>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@18.2.1/build/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
<script>
    const input = document.querySelector("#phone");
    const button = document.querySelector("#btn");
    const errorMsg = document.querySelector("#error-msg");
    const validMsg = document.querySelector("#valid-msg");
    const errorMap = ["Invalid number", "Invalid country code", "Too short", "Too long", "Invalid number"];
    
    const iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
    utilsScript: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intl-tel-input@18.2.1/build/js/utils.js"
});
  const reset = () => {
  input.classList.remove("error");
  errorMsg.textContent = "";
  errorMsg.classList.add("hide");
  validMsg.classList.add("hide");
};

// on click button: validate
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  reset();
  if (input.value.trim()) {
    if (iti.isValidNumber()) {
      validMsg.classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
      input.classList.add("error");
      const errorCode = iti.getValidationError();
      errorMsg.textContent = errorMap[errorCode];
      errorMsg.classList.remove("hide");
    }
  }
});
input.addEventListener('change', reset);
input.addEventListener('keyup', reset);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```